# Extracting bits with bitwise operators

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to learn how to use bitwise operators on a given input but am not having much luck figuring out how to use them.

Let's say I have this following octet:

```
11(01)0000
```

How would I extract the bits between the braces?

Comment: "I didn't know what operators to use". Take pen and paper and write down little examples of ones and zeros. Now with any documentation you can Google, work out what each operator does on your little (pairs of) examples. You'll quickly realize the building blocks you have to solve your problem. Not saying this to be condescending, but you'll thank yourself later for doing that.

Comment: @Bart, I see your point, I know you're not condescending, but the thing is I have 5 days to code a virtual machine, an assembler and a good champion for a corewar, and I'm quite ashamed to admit it but I needed a ready made answer to keep on going, I can't afford even half an hour, I realize the question was quite lame, I'll do better next time !

Comment: I flagged this months ago and got the smackdown. Glad we are not doing peoples' homework.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to:

1. create a suitable mask with ones only where are the bytes you need (you just need to write the number in binary and convert to e.g. hex to put it inside the C program). The parentheses in your `11(01)0000` are your indication to where to put the ones in your mask.

   Alternatively, create a mask made of as many ones as the chunk of bits you are interested in (in your case two ones, i.e. `11` in binary, i.e. `3` in decimal) and left shift it to move it to the position where you need it (left shift operator: `<<`). This approach can be useful if the position of your "bit window" is known only at runtime.
2. Perform a bitwise-and operation between your number and the mask (the bitwise and operator is `&`).

   The bitwise and only leaves as 1 the bits that are 1 in both the operands, so the effect is "filtering" the source number with the bits of the mask: only the bits that correspond to ones in the mask are let "flow through" it, all the other bits are left as zero.
3. Now you have extracted the bits of your interest, but they are still in their original position inside the number. If you want/need it, you can then right shift them to "align them to the right" (use the right shift operator: `>>`).

Comment: Beat me to it. And right on with #3... that was a good refresher for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

Mask your value with the bits you want to select, and shift.

If your 11010000 number is x, the two bit number you want is

```
(x & 0x30 ) >> 4
```

Comment: The usual policy with questions tagged as homework is not to provide ready-made answers...

Comment: Aye. That's why my answer below was trying to explain the operands and where to lead him not provide a single line of code :)